# How to use XML attribute as search criteria in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, xml, attributes

I have an SQL Server table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XMLFiles](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [XML] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [processed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [createtime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [handletime] [datetime] NULL,
    [objectId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ResultText] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [BatchID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_XMLFiles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

The interesting columns in this context are XML and BatchID. The BatchID is unique identifier. My xml data in column XML has a section like this:

```
...
            <CLASSIFICATION>
                <CLASS name="Face Mills Indexable" id="TA_MILL_20_20">
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="-45001" name="Tool Description" datatype="STRING">T990 d100 highfeed</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="-41210" name="Comments" datatype="STRING"/>
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="-41101" name="Supplier" datatype="STRING"/>
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="-45211" name="Plant" datatype="ENUM">4 Lahti</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="160000" name="Machine Tool" datatype="ENUM">BW4 MCR 750</ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="-45212" name="Machine Group" datatype="ENUM"/>
                    <ATTRIBUTE id="-45210" name="Status" datatype="ENUM"/>
...
```

Let's say I'm interested in the value of attribute where id="160000", i.e. the fifth attribute. I can get the value by sql query:

```
SELECT
xml.value('(/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS/ITEM/CLASSIFICATION/CLASS/ATTRIBUTE)[5]','varchar(30)') AS TCODE
FROM XMLFiles
WHERE batchid = '1553762782573'
```

The result is correct: BW4 MCR 750

But, I cannot be sure that this row is always the fifth row here. So I would like to use SQL where I can put the attribute id as search criteria.

Something like this:

```
SELECT something FROM XMLFiles WHERE BacthID='1553762782573'
AND something = '160000'
```

How to get this? I've ran out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath predicate `[@id='160000']` to get nodes where the attribute `id` has a value of `160000`.

```
SELECT xml.value('(/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS/ITEM/CLASSIFICATION/CLASS/ATTRIBUTE[@id=''160000''])[1]','varchar(30)') tcode
       FROM xmlfiles
       WHERE batchid = '1553762782573';
```

You can also use [`exist()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) if you're not interested in the actual value but just want to select rows, where such an element exists in the XML.

```
SELECT *
       FROM xmlfiles
       WHERE batchid = '1553762782573'
             AND xml.exist('/PLM_PUBLISH_ITEM/ITEMS/ITEM/CLASSIFICATION/CLASS/ATTRIBUTE[@id=''160000'']') <> 0;
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for.